# How to remove the "E" in numbers while using .setText?

Tags: java, android

I have a crypto tracking app made, and it deals with very small and very big numbers. I print out the values into a `ListView` while using a custom adapter like this:

```
PriceBox.setText(String.valueOf(price)+"$");
```

and I don't want the `E` to be in it. How can i do that? price is a `double`.

Comment: Why not use a string replace to simply remove all `E`? Or do you want to use something different? Then please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

You can tune format via `String.format()`:

```
String.format("%,.2f $", price);
```

...with `price == 6217.58` , would be formatted as `"6,217.58 $"`

Javadoc:

- ...
- [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- ...